# Помогите исправить код что бы он соответствовал условию задачи

Tags: python

В интервале от A до B найти сумму и количество всех целых чисел, делящихся на 3 без остатка и те которые не делятся на 9 без остатка.

```
A = 1
B = 20
s = 0
c = 0
print("Не делятся на 9 без остатка:", end = ' ')
for i in range(A+1, B):
    if i % 3 == 0:
    s += i
    c += 1
if i % 9 != 0:
    print(i, end = ' ')

print()
print("Информация об элементах делящихся на 3 без остатка:")
print("Сумма:", s)
print("Количество:", c)
```

Answer (score 3):

У Вас отступ отклеился....

После оператора  `if i % 3 == 0:`
И перед `if i % 9 != 0:`

Вы в курсе, что в Python отступы являются синтаксическими элементами?

Comment: это я просто  плохо перенёс код на сайт. В оригинале всё верно.

Comment: @Андрей под вопросом - ссылка "править"

Comment: @Андрей Тогда покажите реальный код и скажите, что с ним не в порядке. Формулировка задачи точная? (`и те которые` выглядит сомнительно)